# JQuery & Javascript: Intermittant mis-matching of clicked div and returned div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, dom

Thanks for giving this a look. I'll start with a quick image. Clicking on any of the red-boxed search results seems to return the `<div>` for the item directly above it.

Here I clicked on `1613 CAROUSEL CIR`, but the event returned the id/content for the item representing `1612..`

[image]

Sometimes it's even weirder, for example, every item following `1420` might point back to `1420`. So it's *not always* a conflict with a `<div>` and it's immediate neighbor, although that's usually the case.

I've been unable to find any definite pattern in this behavior. Sometimes it's just one or two items in the list; sometimes most of the list is affected, with "a good portion" of results pointing to one particular div.

**There's only one true consistency**--typically the first several items work as expected, and short lists will be 100% correct. But really long lists (50+) are *not* necessarily worse than semi-long lists (20+).. :/

The code building the search results iterates over JSON data retrieved by a JQuery `$.ajax()` call, and this is the relevant code building the visible search results:

```
if( result.d.length > 0 )
{
    var i=0;
    for(i; i<result.d.length; i++)
    {
        // ..there's a bunch of irrelevant code here to set the map bounds..
        // ..then I build the HTML using JQuery like this
        //
        var date = new Date();
        var divID = "searchItemDiv" + date.getTime().toString();
        var $searchItemDiv = $( "<div id='" + divID + "' class='searchItemDiv'>"+result.d[i].Description+"</div>" );
        $searchItemDiv.data('itemData', result.d[i]);
        $searchItemDiv.bind('click', onSearchItemClick);
        $( "#searchResults" ).append($searchItemDiv);
    }
}
```

While I don't suspect the event handler is the issue, the relevant code there looks like this:

```
function onSearchItemClick(event)
{
    if( event.target.id.toString() !== '' )
    {
        // I clicked 1613, but event returned DIV with text of "1612"??
        //
        var item = $('#'+event.target.id.toString()).data('itemData');

        alert( event.target.id.toString()+"\n"+ 
                $('#'+event.target.id.toString()).text() );

        // ..more irrelevant stuff to show a popup of property data..
    }
}
```

FireFox, Chrome, and IE all demonstrate the same behavior, so it's not browser-specific.

I'm *relatively sure* this is not the product of a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) during the render phase, but I'm not comfortable-enough with JavaScript to know that for certain.

I'm pretty baffled by this. FWIW, I'm a former Flex & C# developer and relatively new to JavaScript/JQuery development, so there may be a *gotcha* related JavaScript contexts and/or JQuery that I'm stepping into.

Comment: Have you double-checked the JSON to make sure that there are no duplicate values?

Comment: It's almost as if there is a hidden portion of a DIV element extending over the top of result(s) below it, but if I turn on border/background rendering, I don't see any evidence of that..

Comment: hmm, seems strange, do you get the same behaviour if you adressing `this` in the handler? 
e.g. `this.id` or `$(this).text()`

Comment: Any chance you can setup a fiddle and duplicate the behavior? Anything wonky in the console?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, thanks for looking. I've checked the JSON and it's clean. What I don't understand is how clicking on 1613 actually returns a DIV representing 1612. (Accessing the JQuery object's `text()` property should prove that, yes?)

Comment: Have inspected the element on Chrome to narrow down the Problem with the ID's ?? There may be some duplication going around

Comment: Have you checked the searchItemDiv's id's to make sure the previous one is cleared before the new one is written? In other words, are the divID's being written so fast that they could be dupes?

Comment: @JayBlanchard thats exactly why i asked him, if he used `this` , because it would work then...

Comment: @Homungus you addressed the handler, I am addressing the creation of the search items. It wouldn't matter if you changed the handler because if there are duplicate ID's there would be an issue.

Comment: I've got a hunch you guys are right about the `id` values.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, exactly. so when the handler with `this` would work, that would be a hint that your theory is true, that is what i tried to say ...

Comment: @JayBlanchard, the console seems fine, but curiously, when I turn on FireBug, the problem *disappears*----does this support your-guys' assumption that the `id` value is being duplicated? ...I think that makes sense because FireBug should add alot of lag.

Comment: @elrobis turning on FB could introduce enough lag to change the time for the ID's. The answer provided by jshanley makes a lot of sense as it uses your iterator to create the ID's vs. using the time. I also like the declaration of the selector all at once, but I would use on() instead of bind().

Comment: Thanks to all of you for such quick help. I could barely keep up with the feedback. Problem solved. Yes, basically the `div` objects were rendering faster than the `Date()` object's time granularity could support. ...now that I see it with clear eyes, I feel ridiculous for having built it that way in the first place. 
*Muchas gracias, amigos!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, instead of binding the click function within a for-loop, just select all of the searchItemDiv's after the for-loop binds the data to them, and register a click function on all of them at once. You don't need a separate line to define variable `i`, just do it in the for statement. I also wouldn't try to generate random IDs with new `Date`s, that just seems unnecessary. Registering all click functionality at once will also make your click handler much simpler:

```
if( result.d.length > 0 )
{
    for(var i = 0; i<result.d.length; i++)
    {
        // ..there's a bunch of irrelevant code here to set the map bounds..
        // ..then I build the HTML using JQuery like this

        // select the i'th searchItemDiv
        $searchItemDiv = $($('.searchItemDiv')[i])
        // give it the data
        $searchItemDiv.data('itemData', result.d[i]);
        $( "#searchResults" ).append($searchItemDiv);
    }

    // then register all the click handlers at once, very simple
    $('.searchItemDiv').bind('click', function() {
        var item = $(this);
        alert(item.text());
    });
}
```

--EDIT--

also, do the `searchItemDiv`s already exist or are you trying to create them?

if you're trying to create them, you might want this in the for-loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i<result.d.length; i++)
{
    // ..there's a bunch of irrelevant code here to set the map bounds..
    // ..then I build the HTML using JQuery like this

    // create a searchItemDiv
    $searchItemDiv = $('<div class="searchItemDiv"></div>')
    // give it the data
    $searchItemDiv.data('itemData', result.d[i]);
    $( "#searchResults" ).append($searchItemDiv);
}
```

I'm guessing that is what you want to do.

Comment: +1 This is definitely several improvements to the code. I want to rule out the `id` timing as a race-condition first, though. I'll use your implied idea of making `i` the unique value to see if that does the trick.

Comment: Yes, the `id` was the problem all along. Using the `i` value was enough to fix it. I feel like a *blind fool* right now for now using that value in the first place! What did I do, added a heavy `Date()` thug and called `getTime()`. wow that's funny now that the mystery is over. lol Thanks a ton for your help. I'll definitely implement the class binding, rather than the per-object binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem depends on your `searchItemDiv` id.

Using the date doesn't ensure ids are unique so when you retrieve the object by id it will return an element (probably the first) with the same id.

Make sure to assign unique id on your elements.